# Javascript code hide show price * quantity to show total

Tags: javascript, store, show-hide

I have this problem with my code I cant make it to deliver me the answer I want. I want to select one of the options for the product and then one of the options for price then input the quantity and to have the Sub-Total delivered by the code. 
The problem is that since I have different products and each product has 3 different prices I need my code to deliver the right answer.

The code I have right now is only taking the value of the first price of the first product, and I can't seem to make it work, I feel like I almost have the code... please help me :)

```
        <div>Product<br />
    <select id="producto1">
    <option >Selecciona</option>
    <option value="00">---ALARMAS---</option>
    <option value="01">EXTREME BLACK</option>
    <option value="02">EXTREME COBRA</option>
    <option value="03">EXTREME GALACTIC</option>
    </select></div>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="e01">
                <td class="0"> </td>


                <td class="01"><label>Price</label><br />
                <select id="elias">

                <option value="180">180</option>
                <option value="200">200</option>
                <option value="220">220</option>
                </select></td>
                <td class="02"><label>Price</label><br />
                <select id="elias1">

                <option value="50">50</option>
                <option value="20">20</option>
                <option value="22">22</option>
                </select></td>
                <td class="03"><label>Price</label><br />
                <select id="elias2">

                <option value="80">80</option>
                <option value="100">100</option>
                <option value="120">120</option>
                </select></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div>
    <label for="CAT_Custom_500436">Quantity</label><br />
    <input type="text" maxlength="255" name="CAT_Custom_500436" id="CAT_Custom_500436" /></div>
    <div><label for="CAT_Custom_500440">Sub-Total</label><br />
    <input type="text" maxlength="255" name="CAT_Custom_500440" id="CAT_Custom_500440" /></div>
    <br />
```

**Java___**

```
         (function($) {
    $("document").ready(function() {
    $("td").hide();
    $("#producto1").change(function() {
    $(".e01 td").hide();
    $("td." + $(this).val()).show();
    });
    });
    })(jQuery);

var e = document.getElementById("elias");
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

var e = document.getElementById("elias1");
var strUser1 = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

var e = document.getElementById("elias2"); 
var strUser2 = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

$(function () {
$('input').keyup(function (){
var quantity1 = $("#CAT_Custom_500436").val();


var total1 = quantity1 * strUser;
var total1 = quantity1 * strUser1;
var total1 = quantity1 * strUser2;


$("#CAT_Custom_500440").val(total1); 
});
});
```

Comment: Very close, you have 3 prices, but then calculate each of these into the same variable, total1, near the end of you javascript. Since you want to 'deliver the right answer', you probably need to chnage these lines slightly. However you question doesnt explain how we determine which is the 'right answer' from the 3. Maybe clarify how we determine right answer?

Comment: it's a store and the customer is going to select any of the products and any price and select a quantity and have the code to deliver the total. its a matter of any price you select no matter the product just the price and value that that price has * the quantity. All I want is to have the whatever price selected of whatever product i have on the list multiplied by the quantity and have the Subtotal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something in these lines

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
     // Cache the variables
     var $elias = $('#elias'),
         $elias1 = $('#elias1'),
         $elias2 = $('#elias2'),
         $product = $('#producto1'),
         $error = $('.error'),
         $container = $('.container');
     $("td").hide();
     var productValue;
     $product.change(function () {
         $(".e01 td").hide();
         $("td." + $(this).val()).show();
         // Only show the container when the selections are not first 2
         if (this.value !== 'Selecciona' && this.value !== '00') {
             $error.addClass('hide');
             $container.removeClass('hide');
         } else {
             $error.removeClass('hide');
             $container.addClass('hide');
         }
         productValue = this.value;
     }).change();
     // Bind the change event for Dropdowns
     var $quantity = $('#CAT_Custom_500436'),
         $total = $("#CAT_Custom_500440");

     $elias.add($elias1).add($elias2).change( findTotal);
     $quantity.keyup(findTotal);

     function findTotal() {
         // Get the value
         var quan = $quantity.val();
         var pri = $('.'+ productValue).find('select').val();
         var tot = pri * quan;
         $total.val(tot);

     }
 });
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/rgDNh/)**

Comment: Thank you very much !! thats just what i was looking for :D thank you very much !! you just saved me a ton of time!

Comment: Glad to have helped :)